# Get pause state of matinee node in kismet

Tags: unreal-development-kit, kismet-udk

I have set up an elevator in the UDK so that if a generator goes offline, it will pause the elevator. Everything works fine, but when the generator comes back online, you have to touch the trigger volume for the elevator to get it to resume its animation. For instance, someone is riding the elevator and the generator goes down, the elevator pauses. Great. When the generator comes back online, I don't have a way to resume the paused matinee.

I would need a set up in kismet that would see, if the generator is online, and the elevator matinee node is paused, then play the animation.

So, my question is, is there a way to check in kismet if a matinee node is in a pause state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a Kismet boolean variable bPaused. When you need to pause the Matinee, first set bPaused to true with a SetVariable action, then pause the Matinee. Check the bPaused variable with the rest of your Kismet when you need to know whether the Matinee is paused.

Make sure to reset bPaused to false when resuming the animation.